# Edittext field next defers to itself

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm trying to make it so if a user selects an edittext box, it clears it.  Now through trying to do this, it appears that hitting next still keeps the focus in the same text box and clears it.  I tried

```
rows = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
cols = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
ticks = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

rows.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        rows.setText("");
        //cols.requestFocus();
    }
});

cols.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        cols.setText("");
        //ticks.requestFocus();
    }
});

ticks.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ticks.setText("");
    }
});
```

now i tried doing request focus in the onclick, which successfully moves the focus to the the next edittext, but it clears what was in the previous edittext as it does that.  How can I make the edittexts clear the text when a user selects it, yet still retain it's normal "next" properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to try with onTouchListener.

```
        ed.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            ((EditText)v).setText("");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Just what i was looking for, thanks.  Quick question, what is the different really between onTouch and onClick for this problem?